# How to resolve 'internet connection' error for pydev configuration in eclipse market place?

Tags: pydev, eclipse-marketplace

I have tried with below setting but not working

Window-> Preferences-> General->Network connection->Active provider- Manual

Error details:
Cannot open eclipse market place
Cannot install eclipse market place location:
Connection failed

This most often caused by a problem with your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it happens to you (I guess you probably have a spotty net connection or some firewall in place).

Other things you can try:

- install without using the marketplace client. See: http://www.pydev.org/download.html for details (i.e.: you can use http://www.pydev.org/updates as the update site).
- download a .zip from sourceforge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/) and then extract it yourself in the Eclipse `dropins` folder (and restart Eclipse).

Comment: On the client machine, I am not able to download a .zip from  (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/). It is blocking due to an internet connection setting. Is there any other way to download it safely?

Comment: This is probably why you also can't get it to install properly from the pydev update site... As for another way, no, right now it's only available as an update site from pydev.org or as a binary from sourceforge (so, you'll have to get an internet connection which supports accessing at least one of those).

Comment: Actually, on a 2nd thought, you could try to `curl` the whole update site from the actual source instead of the pydev.org redirect (https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/7.6.0/) and then install it as a local update site.